# Is it correct that, you can NOT use foreign credit cards, whatsoever, in Japan in train ticket machines? (As of 2023.)

Tags: trains, japan, payment-cards

In Japan at train stations, you can very easily buy a ticket, shinkansen or other service, at the ticket machines just by the gate.

There are (A) "credit card only" machines and (B) machines that take either cash (ie, notes/coins) or credit card.

All machines have an English button /often other languages too and you can easily select the train, seat etc if relevant, and pay.

HOWEVER I was astonished to see that very simply, it seems foreign credit cards, foreign cards of any type, are just not accepted.

As a curiosity I tried this extensively at many stations and many ticket machines, and indeed where the staff / locals etc spoke enough English, as best as I could understand indeed, amazingly, that's the case.

If you need a train ticket and you particularly want to pay using credit card, you have to stand in line (allow minimum one hour in almost all cases, since tourists flock to the ticket counter) at the ticket office;

or simply get cash from an ATM and use cash in the ticket machines, which is dead easy.

(Just TBC ordinary foreign credit cards work completely normally as anywhere in the world and are accepted everywhere in Japan for everything, in my experience. (Shops, restaurants, etc etc.))

Somewhat surprisingly, I thought there would be 100 million web pages where Otaku travellers yell about how ah hah! surprisingly! no foreign cards at Japanese train ticket machines!  But no, I really can't see any solid info on it.

Does anyone **decisively know if it's a plain fact that JR ticket machines simply do *not* accept foreign credit cards**?

It could be I'm missing something or making some sort of mistake.

---

Related footnote - it's funny we live in an era when the internet has been around long enough that info on the net goes out of date really quickly. There are a million posts on the internet that *JAPAN IS A CASH SOCIETY YOU CAN'T USE CARDS TOURIST BEWARE CARRY ONLY CASH IN JAPAN* etc.  Of course, this is absolutely wrong and ancient history now, you use normal international cards everywhere and always in Japan these days. This question is only about the weird curiosity of JR ticket machines!

Comment: If you have an iPhone, there's a neat workaround: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/176293/9009

Comment: Fascinating, you know, I'm not sure if that helps if one specifically wants to pay by credit card (eg, 200 - 1000 buck of tickets for self/family on shinkansen, and you specifically want to use a credit card rather than deduct it from your shrinking bank balance!)  :)

Comment: Just a quick note that the pandemic seems to have had a big effect on the "cash society" thing. I was here six months before the pandemic and have been back for over two months and in many situations, but not all, when cash was the only way before, I've been able to use my card now. Some places even preferred card. (The same happened in Australia but to a less noticeable extent, places that had $10 minimum for card purchase dropped the minimum.)

Comment: *as anywhere in the world* — that's a bit of an overstatement.  The world is a big place.

Comment: keep in mind that there are several systems used by credit cards and especially debit cards, depending largely on the country they are issued, and not all machines in all countries are compatible with all cards. E.g. Canadian and US sales terminals won't accept EU debit cards but will accept EU credit cards. I've also found that Indonesian ATMs will accept EU debit cards but Indonesian sales terminals won't.

Comment: JW, right. Debit cards are more fussy and there's a number of networks.  Credit cards are more straightforward. (This Q is about credit cards; you cannot use debit cards at all in JR Shinkansen ticket machines.) (Which is also bizarre.) Normal credit cards work everywhere in Japan except - seemingly - JR Shinkansen ticket machines.  It strikes me as incredible that this isn't a "well know fact", and/or there aren't clear mentions about it on eg. JR web sites etc. Given than 100% of tourists to Japan, as soon as they rush to a soap house and then the Pokemon center, take a bullet train!  WTH?!

Comment: @jwenting my EU debit card works just fine in every store in the US.

Comment: @Fattie Are you sure that a, say, EU-issued VISA *credit* card works in Japan differently than an EU-issued VISA *debit* card? I can't believe that.

Comment: @JonathanReez-onstrike mine didn't a few years ago.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko yes, it's very normal that visa debit and visa credit cards work totally differently (that applies in the world generally, including the US, and it's irrelevant where it's issued)

Comment: @Fattie I'm not convinced. The payment processing infrastructure must be the same, why would VISA have multiple independent systems? Judging by the answers to your question, other users also report different experiences.

Comment: hi Jonny,sure seek more info elsewhere

Answer (score 8):

This is absolutely not true. I have used various foreign-issued cards at ticket vending machines operated by various JR companies and I have rarely had an issue. However, be well aware that not *all* cards would work. If your card is issued by Visa, MasterCard or American Express (or JCB, but that is very rare outside of East and Southeast Asia) and carries a chip, there is a good chance it would work. Amex cards seem to have the best chance of working, quite ironically.

Regardless, it's still a bad idea to go around Japan without carrying cash. Many places are still cash only; some have gone cashless recently but accept only QR codes, and yet others may accept cards but yours might not work.

Comment: This is great information - just TBC were your cards **USA** cards?  Below, someone mentioned using UK cards which worked.  (I have only Visa and MC, and I have about 5 of each, all with chip, and I tried every single one and not one worked, at five different stations.) (March 2023)

Comment: @Fattie Yes, several US cards worked. Visa and Amex. It seems that Amex has the best chance of working.

Comment: @Fattie It's not too late to get an Amex card I guess! They've nerfed the benefits significantly though.

Comment: I'm wondering was this to buy shinkansen tickets (shinkansen machines), or to buy subway and other JR tickets ?

Comment: Was this within the last year or so?  When did this happen? Before covid?

Comment: @Fattie Well before COVID. ~2018. Subway ticket vending machines do not even take cards, usually. But some JR vending machines do, Shinkansen or not.

Comment: hi xuq18, thanks for that info. So you're talking 5+ years ago.  I've been wondering if they STOPPED taking foreign cards, due to the border closure year.  As I've mentioned, at the eg. shin yokahama station, the shinkansen ticket machines have hand-made scribbled "No foreign cards" banner on some pieces of A4 paper.

Comment: (Regarding the subway, all machines take credit cards - BUT - as far as I know only for charging your pasmo/whatever, you can't buy a ticket using a credit card.)

Comment: (Just FYI.  Regarding the last para in your answer which is unrelated to the specific question.  To me this seems very out of date now. In my experience I've literally found not one place, literally nowhere, that is now cash only, including the smallest yakiniku, onsen etc!  (Perhaps since it's now completely trivial for anyone to get a swiper from Square and the 100 other companies doing that; if you have and know how to use a 1000 $ phone, it costs $10 for square to send you a swiper to use with it) )

Comment: BTW xuq I was completely mystified by the fact that I couldn't use a US card in the shinkansen machines, as I think I've read often that you can (just by an odd coincidence, I've never had to take a shinkansen before, whilst in Japan).  Maybe there's been some change?  IDK  I'll try to find a more-English speaking JR person to find out !!  It's a minor mystery.

Comment: I noticed a fair amount of Japanese companies stopped accepting (some) foreign cards around the same time. Suica app seems to only take Amex and certain MCs? I only have Visas, so I can only attest to the "not being able to use" part. May be some policy change, either the card-side or the company-side. Also I couldn't use my cards on the machine for the Keisei Skyliner last month FWIW.

Comment: @Fattie Depends on which subway you're talking about. Maybe Tokyo Metro takes cards, I don't think many subway operators do.

Comment: For cash only places, it really depends on where you go. Many small ramen shops and other fast food joints still only take cash (and perhaps PayPay), but yeah probably tourists don't tend to go to these places; I live in Japan. But yeah, Amex is quite widely accepted so still the best bet when it comes to cards.

Answer (score 5):

I've been in Japan in November/December 2022, and bought tickets from JR machines at Kyoto station (and other places) using a UK MasterCard issued by Starling bank. I think I also used another card successfully, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Thanks .. as you recall, was that to buy a shinkansen ticket, or, to buy perhaps a metro or similar ticket or pass?  (I was literally just in Kyoto last week, and tried to buy a shinkansen ticket back to osaka (20 bucks) and I absolutely couldn't, trying many both MC / Visa (US banks, not UK banks), and indeed a staffer said to me "no foreign card, no foreign card"  -!  heh)

Comment: For all I know I've just been using totally the wrong slot, or something, all along :)  Anything's possible ..

Comment: @Fattie Does your credit card have a microchip or magnetic stripe? In the past this was a problem with cards without a microchip.

Comment: Mark, I have 11 (wth!) different USA credit cards with me. (they are all chip-n-pin, and I think most are tap these days also) Just as you say "chip problems" are often an issue. That does not seem to be the issue; they all read perfectly. (Also again as mentioned, the cards of mine work completely perfectly at the ordinary visa/mc card reader in the "walk up" shinkansen ticket shop at JR stations.) It's a mystery!

Comment: @Fattie This article implies that there is no general local cards only policy. They may be in transition in the implementation of general credit card usage. [2023-03-30: Japanese transportation companies look to credit cards as cheaper payment option - Asia News NetworkAsia News Network](https://asianews.network/japanese-transportation-companies-look-to-credit-cards-as-cheaper-payment-option/) *Paying for public transportation by credit card is expected to spread further when more overseas tourists come to Japan in the near future.*

Comment: @Fattie There was definitely a Shinkansen ticket I bought by card, probably also a regular JR ticket.

Comment: @Arno thanks for that - maybe UK cards work ?!  But not US.  I don't have any UK cards with me to test.

Comment: @MarkJohnson - interesting; you know that seems to be focussing on the idea of directly using a credit card to tap at the gate (rather than the current 1950s solution where you have to get a suica card, or whatever it's called, to tap at the gate.  You know, I will add a couple photos of the JR Shinkansen ticket machines (some of which indeed have scribbled notes stuck on by the staff "no foreign card").  But it seems that Arno's UK card worked.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you want to use an IC card (Suica/pasmo etc) rather than paper ticket then these cannot be topped up with any credit/debit card whatsoever.

Comment: This is incorrect as of 2024. You can install the Suica app on your phone, add the card to your phone wallet, and top it up easily with Apple or Google Pay.